# Dynamic property names within object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamic, properties

My original purpose was to create variables with dynamic names, in order to avoid repeated statements of  `var randName = document.createElement("div");`.
So, at the time, I was just learning about JS objects, and I thought I could do something like this:

```
var createMe = function(){},
elemsArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
numbersArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
togetherArray = elemsArray.concat(numbersArray),
i;
for(i = 0; i < togetherArray.length; i++)
{
    createMe.prototype[togetherArray[i]] = document.createElement("div");
    createMe.prototype[togetherArray[i]].setAttribute("id", togetherArray[i]); 
}
var awesomeObject = new createMe;
```

So now, I can reference the HTML elements by awesomeObject.body, for instance, and manipulate them, insert them into DOM, etc...
With this, I save a bunch of lines of code, and it works, and works for what I want, however, I wonder if what I'm doing doesn't break any rules, is slow, or is the best approach. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wonder if this is the only way of doing it? Or maybe with a function inside the object that takes arrays as an input and adds the properties?

Comment: Well there are all sorts of ways to dynamically create properties. Which one is "better" or "worse" depends on the problems you're trying to solve.

Comment: Alright then, thank you. I guess this question is kind of pointless then... Should I leave it open?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for suggestions on simpler ways to accomplish your goal might I suggest something like:

```
var createMe = function(ids) {
    elems = {};
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
        elems[id] = '<div id="'+id+'"></div>';
    }
    return elems;
}
var awesomeObject = createMe(['a','b','c','d','e'].concat([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Granted this returns the elements as strings instead. I find it is often easier to work with HTML strings when creating nodes, only using the DOM API to alter existing nodes. Adding string nodes to the page via [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) is efficient and if you wish to turn this strings intro nodes for some step [$.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) is available as well as helper functions accomplishing the same.